# Login to SharePoint using PnP PowerShell Module and an Access Token

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, module, token, pnp-js

This is my first question here in the community!

I'm trying to connect to a SharePoint site using the PnP PowerShell Module and an access token, but I'm still not being able to make it work.

The script is the following:

```
# Import the MSAL Module to generate the access token
Import-Module MSAL.PS

# Generating the token (this brings other fields too, like 'ExpireOn' or 'TokenType')
$token1 = Get-MsalToken -ClientId xxx -ClientSecret $(convertto-securestring("xxx") -AsPlainText -Force) -TenantId xxx

# Saving only the 'Access Token' field value into the variable
$token1 = $token1.AccessToken

# Trying to connect using the token
connect-pnpOnline -Url "https://boehringerdev.sharepoint.com/sites/z365SupportSite" -AccessToken $token1
```

The error is the following:

```
Connect-PnPOnline: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Identity.Client, Version=4.50.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a613f4dd989e8ae'. Could not find or load a specific file. (0x80131621)
```

I also tried to convert the token into a secure-string using the following cmdlet:

```
$secureToken = ConvertTo-SecureString $token1 -AsPlainText –Force
```

But when I try to used the secureToken I get the same error.

Could anyone help me, PLEASE?? THANKS IN ADVANCE!!

I'm trying to connect to a SharePoint Site (Dev Tenant) using a token and I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the PnP.PowerShell module is incompatible with the Microsoft.Identity.Client assembly.To fix this error, you can try to uninstall the latest version and install the previous version of the PnP.PowerShell module. You can do this by running the following command in PowerShell:

```
Install-Module PnP.PowerShell -RequiredVersion 1.12 -Force
```

After installing the previous version, please try to use the Connect-PnPOnline command again and check if the problem exists.

Comment: Don't forget to close your PowerShell window and restart the session after updating the module. I beat my head against the wall for a while before learning that.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes as Powershell scrpt uses Microsoft.Identity.Client, Version 4.37.0.0 which is installed with msal.ps. We have to delete it and then we have intall Microsoft.Identity.Client, Version 4.5.0.0.